# How To Make One Setup(Wix) From Two different setups(Wix) ? (C#)

Tags: c#, wix

I have two different solutions(C#), for each solution i have:

1. The software project.
2. The installation project(WIX).

How can i create from the two solutions a one setup that combine the two softwares?

It is possible to display in the instillation process two checkboxs that display the two softwares and i could choose which softwares to install? (one of them or both of them)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to make a third installer that chain install the other two MSI packages.

Here's an example of a .wxs file that does this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
  <Bundle Name="UNIFIED DERPER"
          Version="1.0.0.0"
          Manufacturer="STERKERVERFLER"
          UpgradeCode="Some Guid Here">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" >
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication        
        LicenseFile="License.rtf"
        LogoFile="logo.bmp"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
    <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf"
                 Value="License.rtf" />
    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.ProjectOneInstaller.TargetDir)ProjectOne.msi"
                  DisplayInternalUI="yes" />
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.ProjectTwoInstaller.TargetDir)ProjectTwoInstaller.msi"
                  DisplayInternalUI="yes"  />
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Comment: What i need to do with this XML ? Open a new solution with just one project(wix installer) and use this XML? and point to the source file of the other two installation ? or what ?
And do i get a list of the software i want to install?(the check box i mention earlier..)
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think its provide a check box or some list to choose what will be installed and what not, because i have two different software that i want the one ".msi" need to include but the user can decide which to install, and i cant find anything online about this option(if it exists..)

Comment: @RonKah: You have to create your own UI for that.  Seems like it's time for you to find a much more friendly product.  WiX is not easy at all to use.